# Blank screen after login Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

After login in Ubuntu just blank screen. I tried to reinstall a fresh copy. But only keep showing window with pci servcity corrected.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+F2 work?

Comment: Hi, I tried Ctrl+Alt+F1 nothing happened. Thank you for sharing it but nothing happened also. Yesterday everything was working fine until I noticed that another boot sector been created windows  10 in addition to Ubuntu which I did not but rather erased the entire hard drive. My pc is Haunted.